# How can i show/echo names related to multiple id

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show this result

Bodypart1,Bodypart2

Table Excersise
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPbFU.jpg)

Table Bodyparts
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1OeP.jpg)

My Code:

```
$sql = "
SELECT x.*
     , b.bodypart_name bodypart
  FROM exercises x
     , equipments e
     , bodyparts b
 WHERE x.exercise_bodypart = b.bodypart_id
 ";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$exercises = $statement->fetchAll();

?>

<table>
<th>Bodypart</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php foreach($exercises as $exercise): ?>

echo $exercise['bodypart'];


?></span></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) // fetches restults into an associative array

Comment: Is there any relationship between equipments and the other tables?

Comment: So how is `equipment` linked to any of the other 2 tables

Comment: The HTML is a mess. I see a `</span>` but no `<span>`

Comment: You are preparing a SQL statement with no parameters! Why?

Comment: You are not checking that the execution of the query actually succeeded, my guess it does not

Comment: `exercise_bodypart` is a comman delimited list of keys. **Bad database design** and means you query will not do as you expect

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are just to many errors in this code

Comment: @RiggsFolly - While I agree that this question is riddled with errors, it may actually be a valuable search term for the knowledge base. Please review my answer which redesigns the database before closing.

Comment: @idiotprovider Closing is not just up to me, 4 others must agree and also offer up a close vote

Answer (score 0):

`$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` // fetches results into an associative array.

also you forgot the opening `<td><span>`

Comment: you should var_dump($exercises) and see if your query is returning what you thought it was

Comment: i want to change on echo bodypart_id by bodypart_name

Answer (score 0):

First of all your database structure is a bit off.

```
#Your excercise_bodypart field contains multiple keys, remove the field.
ALTER TABLE test_answer_override
DROP COLUMN exercise_bodypart;

#Build a bridge table which will establish a many to many relationship between exercises and bodyparts.
CREATE TABLE exercise_body_part
    exercise_id INT NOT NULL,
    bodypart_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (exercise_id,bodypart_id),
    KEY exercise_id (exercise_id),
    KEY bodypart_id (bodypart_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_exercise_bodypart FOREIGN KEY (`bodypart_id`) REFERENCES `bodyparts`(`bodypart_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_bodypart_exercise FOREIGN KEY (`exercise_id`) REFERENCES `exercise`(`exercise_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;

#Insert the rows needed that were removed with the deletion of exercise_bodypart field in step one above.
INSERT INTO excercise_body_part(exercise_id,bodypart_id) VALUES(5,8),(5,9);
```

What you're missing here is a JOIN. For the purposes of this question though it was not stipulated so, I'm going to assume that you really want more than to list the bodyparts but will also be listing the exercises as well. Now let's tackle the query:

```
SELECT 
  exercises.*,
  bodyparts.bodypart_name AS 'bodypart' 
FROM bodyparts 
JOIN exercise_body_part ON bodyparts.bodypart_id=exercise_body_part.bodypart_id
JOIN excercise ON exercise_bodypart.exercise_id=exercise.exercise_id
ORDER BY bodypart;
```

As far as your HTML goes, it looks like you have an error where you aren't matching your PHP tags. Maybe something like this is what you're looking for?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Body Part</th>
    <th>Exercises</th>
  <tr>
<?php 
$currentBodypart="";
foreach($exercises as $exercise){
  if($currentBodypart!=$exercise['bodypart']){
    $currentBodypart=$exercise['bodypart'];
    //create a new row and add the first column with the bodypart name ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?=$exercise['bodypart'];?></td><td>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Reps</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$exercise['exercise_title'];?></td>
        <td><?=$exercise['exercise_reps'];?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <?php 
  }
  if($currentBodypart!=$exercise['bodypart']){
    //close of the cell containing exercises and end the new row ?>
  </td></tr>
  <?php }
}?>
</table>
```

The HTML without the PHP might look something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Bodypart</th>
        <th>Exercises</th>
      <tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bodypart 1</td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Reps</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Exercise 1</td>
                <td>12</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Break your tasks down into smaller pieces and you will experience success. First make sure the query is running. Then make sure PHP is working and you are getting data back from the database by using the var_dump() function. Then, try something like the plain HTML example to get your template correct. Finally, plug in the data that is being pulled from MySQL into your page via PHP.

Comment: Also, on a side note it is recommended that table names not be plural as it leads to more readable SQL syntax. Establishing a relationship between a body part and an exercise sounds more reasonable than establishing a relationship between body parts and exercises though that may be the desired result. When naming tables think of the table as a collection of records and almost always each record represents a singular entity (in your case, a body part and an exercise).

Comment: Thank you, but I want to make it dynamic without WHERE bodyparts.bodypart_name IN ("Bodypart1",Bodypart2"); Or changing something in this part.

Comment: Remove the where clause then. Your syntax above showed a join within the where clause and one table (equipment) which was not even joined. Syntactically there is nothing wrong with putting your relationships in the where clause, it's just not standard. The where clause is typically used for limiting results to a specific set. If you want to show all body parts then there would not be a where clause.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working about it in more detail? Have you tested the query in a database administration tool like MySQL Workbench or Navicat to make sure it is returning data? Are you getting an error? Is it a white screen? At a minimum you should see the words "Bodyparts" and "Exercises" from your table heading. If you are not then that implies there is another error. In the snippet you attached you're missing an opening <html> and <body> tag at the beginning of the HTML.

Comment: You are also missing the opening php tag at the top of the file add <?php

Comment: i want to change the outputs (8,9,) to (Bodypart1,Bodypart2)

Comment: You are unlikely getting any output. True?. My recommendation upon further consideration (looked at the images of your tables) is that you need a bridge table called exercise_body_part. The exercise_body_part table will only contain two fields, excercise_id and bodypart_id. I have added the create and alter table syntax you need to another SQL block in my answer above. Please note that the create, alter, and insert statements do NOT need to run in the page and should only be executed once from the command line or workbench.

Comment: I also updated the query to account for the bridge table. Also please note that the query to be ran in the PHP page now requires two joins to join the exercises table and the bodyparts table. I know this might seem like a big change but it really isn't. Don't get overwhelmed. Just do one thing at a time. Programming is hard. I've been writing code for thirteen years. Hope this helps. You can't join multiple values from a single field without multiple queries.